# sum matrix using logical matrix - index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices.

- mcaps which is a double 1698 x 2
- index_g which is a logical 1698 x 2

When using the line of code below I get the error message that Index exceeds matrix dimensions. I don't see how this is the case though?

```
    tsp = nansum(mcaps(index_g==1, :));
```

**Update**

Sorry I should have mentioned that I need the sum of each column in the mcaps vector

** Example of data **

```
mcaps                   index_g
5      6                0      0
4      3                0      0
6      5                1      1
4      6                0      1
8      7                0      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here. I missed one. Original answer is below.

What I missed is that when you use the logical index in this way, you are picking out elements of the matrix that may have different numbers of elements in each column, so MATLAB can't return a well formed matrix back to `nansum`, and so returns a vector. To get around this, use the fact that `0 + anything = 0`

```
% create a mask of values you don't want to sum. Note that since
% index_g is already logical, you don't have to test equal to 1.
mask = ~index_g & isnan(mcaps)

% create a temporary variable
mcaps_to_sum = mcaps;

% change all of the values that you don't want to sum to zero
mcaps_to_sum(mask) = 0;

% do the sum
sum(mcaps_to_sum,1);
```

This is basically all that the `nansum` function does internally, is to set all of the `NaN` values to zero and then call the sum function.

---

`index_g == 1` returns a 1698 x 2 logical matrix, but then you add in an extra dimension with the colon. To sum the columns, use the optional `dim` input. You want:

```
tsp = nansum(mcaps(index_g == 1),1);
```

Comment: ah sorry I should have mentioned that I want the sum of each column in the mcaps matrix

Comment: that returns me a 650 x1 double vector

Comment: Sorry, I always get my rows and columns mixed up. Sum on dimension 1 instead of dimension 2.

Comment: that return a single number not two